# Bulk insert from Excel to SQLite without TXT or CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, sqlite

I have a problem and I hope to get some input from any of you.

Basically, I need to write a code in VBA which enables me to take a table of data from excel to sqlite.

I have managed to do it using this code:

```vb
Sub Scrivi()
    Dim objConnection As Object, objRecordset As Object
    Dim strDatabase As String

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    strDatabase = "DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\TestDB.db;"

    Query = "drop table FUND; create table FUND (Fund_Code, Fund_Name, End_Date, PRIMARY KEY('Fund_Code'));"
    riga = 3
    colonna = 1
    While Not (IsNull(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value) Or IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value))
        Query = Query & "insert into FUND values('" & Cells(row, column) & "','" & Cells(row, column + 1) & "','" & Cells(row, column + 2) & "');"
        row = row + 1
    Wend

    objConnection.Open strDatabase
    objConnection.Execute Query
    objConnection.Close 
End Sub
```

Now I would like to change the iterative part in which I say `row = row + 1` with a sort of bulk insert in which the program takes the whole table instead of doing it row by row.

I do not want a creation of csv/txt file if it is possible.

Thank you very much, any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic level solution can be through first building the complete query for bulk insert and then execute the query in one go.

For Example -

insert into FUND values(val1, val2);
insert into FUND values(val3, val4);

can be replaced with - 
insert into FUND values(val1, val2),(val3, val4)

Comment: thank you for the info. you are right but what if I decide to create another row? then I have to modify the code again! I would like to eliminate the "while not" sentence with a more effective and less time consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

you could append all data from worksheet.range into array(variant)

```
Dim arr as Variant
arr = Application.Transpose(range(your_range_of_data).values)
```

and then, using data in array, build SQL query string using this pattern

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... ),
(expression1, expression2, ... ),
...;
```

VBA Function (written 'on the knee', so it might require a little bit of tweaking, sorry)

```
Function buildQueryFromArray(arr as Variant, table as String, columns as String) as String
    Dim strSqlQuery as String * 4096 
    Dim i as Integer

    strSqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " & table & " (" & columns & ") VALUES"
    For i=LBound(arr, 1) to UBound(arr, 1)
        strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery & "(" & arr(i,1) & ", " & arr(i,2) & "etc" & "),"
    Next i
    buildQueryFromArray = Left(strSqlQuery, len(strSqlQuery)-1) & ";"
End Function
```

reason for using array instead of grabbing data directly from worksheet is: its much much faster. You can read more here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

lemme know if that works for you : )

---

**EDIT:**
Ad1: you're right, we actually don't want to transpose it. *however, I got used to write this way because of the reasons which are well described in post #7 in this topic:* [mrexcel.com/forum/ Why we use application.transpose?](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629320-application-transpose-visual-basic-applications-array.html#post3122898)
Ad2: no, it doesn't have to be in function if this is your question, but it makes code cleaner and more reusable. Below you can find inline solution:

```
Sub Scrivi()
Dim objConnection As Object, objRecordset As Object
Dim strDatabase As String, strQuery as String 

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

strDatabase = "DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\TestDB.db;"

strQuery = "drop table FUND; create table FUND (Fund_Code, Fund_Name, End_Date, PRIMARY KEY('Fund_Code')); insert into FUND values"

'determine how many rows of data there is
Dim lastRow as Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'transfer all data from range to array
'range: from A3 to Cx, where x equals to lastRow
Dim arr as Variant
arr =

 ActiveSheet.Range("A3:C" & lastRow).Value

    'add all records from arr into single SQL query
    'Lbound(xArray, xDimension)/Ubound(xArray, xDimension) - returns integer equal to first/last xArray item in xDimension. Everyday-use function. Google some more to have better insight of whats going on
    Dim i as Integer
    For i=Lbound(arr,1) to Ubound(arr,1)
    strQuery = strQuery & "(" & arr(i,1) & "," & _
                                arr(i,2) & "," & _
                                arr(i,3) & "),"
Next i

'from the strQuery - swap last comma for semi-colon
strQuery = Left(strQuery, len(strQuery)-1) & ";"

objConnection.Open strDatabase
objConnection.Execute strQuery
objConnection.Close
```

Lemme know if everything is clear :)

Comment: thanks for the input! this is my first time using VBA for something more (creating connection etc.). so I am a bit confused.
I have some question:

1) why application.transpose? I do not want a transpose matrix
2) the function is fundametal for the code to go on right? I think so but I want confirmation

thanks again ;)

Comment: too much code for comment so I had to EDIT. Feel free to ask any questions that'll come to your head

Comment: ok everything seems to be clear. just one thing:

why this part of the code?

" 'from the strQuery - swap last comma for semi-colon
strQuery = Left(strQuery, len(strQuery)-1) & ";" "

Comment: @StevenIngo sorry for delay.
after your strQuery exits For-loop it will have comma(",") at the end, however SQL syntax requires from you to put semi-colon(";") at the end.
Therefore we want to take string whole string minus last character: `Left(strQuery, len(strQuery)-1)`, where `len(strQuery)-1` returns us lenght of the string minus 1, and `Left(str, len(str)-1)` provides us with whole string minus last character. Then we simply add semi-colon by typing `& ";"` at the end